# Is it impossible for Sarada to get an Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan?

Tags: naruto-gaiden, boruto

According to the [Naruto wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan):

> Their vision can be restored by transplanting the Mangekyō Sharingan of an Uchiha with strong blood ties — ideally a sibling — thus awakening the so-called Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan

Since Sarada doesn't have any siblings, this means that the closest relative to her with the Uchiha blood would be her father. Apparently, since this is not ideal, does it mean that Sarada will never obtain the Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would Sarada have to kill Boruto to obtain the Mangekyou Sharingan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/42584/would-sarada-have-to-kill-boruto-to-obtain-the-mangekyou-sharingan)

Comment: @AkiTanaka I’m not sure if it is entirely a duplicate. That question is asking about the standard Mangekyou. This is asking about the Eternal Mangkeyou

Comment: @Wondercricket I acknowledge that I'm not an expert in *Naruto* franchise at all. However, the last sentence on the question reads "awaken the (standard) Mangekyou Sharingan" to me, which is already answered in the dupe. Now, I don't know if it's possible to get Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan without obtaining the standard Mangekyou Sharingan first... (anyway, there's still Close Vote Review Queue where the community can decide to leave this open or not. You have stated the reason to not close it, which can be helpful for the reviewer)

Comment: All though the 2 questions are closely related, the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan is something different from the Mangekyou Sharingan, containing different requirements to unlock. The accepted answer in the duplicate covers one of those scenario's in 1 sentence, however this would not fully answer the question asked here. Hence I think we should leave it open

Comment: @AkiTanaka I agree that before the edits, this would look like a duplicate to someone who doesn't know about the Regular and Eternal Mangekyou. However, for everyone, there has been an edit to the question since then, fixing the sentence in question to properly reference the Eternal Mangekyou instead of the regular one. Referencing the regular mangekyou in this context makes no sense at all, so the edit is correct, and as such, it should be clear this is not quite a duplicate. They are unlocked differently, and the wiki references can be found in this question and the others accepted answer.

Comment: `'Since Sarada doesn't have any siblings, this means that the closest to her (with the Uchiha blood) would be her father.'`

Just because you do not know of the person, doesn't mean he or she doesn't exist.

Comment: Note that I've edited your question to remove uncertainy phrases like "might it be impossible". These uncertainty phrases make it more difficult to understand the question and to answer it objectively. If you feel that I've changed the meaning of your question, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not ideal to give Sarada Sasuke's eyes for an Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan while he's alive. It is possible that she gains it while Sasuke is about to die (kind of like how Kakashi got the Sharingan from Obito). Another way would be to have a genetic clone (which would satisfy the condition of close blood ties) awaken a Mangekyou Sharingan and transplant it to Sarada. (Although the latter is highly improbable)